# Link to a file share through an anchor tag

Tags: html

How do I format an HTML anchor tag to link to a shared network folder?

I tried the following and it does not like it.

```
<a href="file:\\myserver\myfolder\myfile.docx">My Shared Folder</a>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this URL:

```
<a href="file://///myserver/myfolder/myfile.docx">
```

Comment: And if the path has special characters and spaces?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the correct mark up is:

```
    <a href="file:///\\serverpath\folder\filename.ext">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="file:///myserver/myfolder/myfile.docx">My Shared Folder</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it should formatted like this:

```
file:///TheComputerNameOrIpAddress/FolderName/myFile.docx
```

I'm not 100% sure that will work, but it's worth a shot.  Good luck.