# Load local video using html source path attribute from remote html in UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, video, uiwebview

I'm creating an app where a remote html loads into UIWebView and needs to access a locally stored mp4 video file.

I've tried subclassing NSURLCache class which allowed me to substitute remote images for local ones stored in the documents directory but can't seem to do the same for videos. Makes sense since videos typically don't get cached.

Does anyone know of any trick that I can use?

Comment: Did you try creating absolute path and using it in src parameter for video?

Comment: I've tried using the absolute path: _"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/79066D46-BBF4-4C77-B27A-7DA8F3EB8042/Documents/test.mp4"_ but it just looks for it on the server.

Comment: This question might be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021781/the-right-way-of-setting-a-href-when-its-a-local-file

Comment: I've tried the variations of _file://_ with 1,2,3 slashed and various string lengths, and nothing has worked :(

Comment: In the link I gave it says that such thing is impossible due to security reason. Web page can't talk to local resourses, it is forbidden. It can talk only if the web page was loaded from local. Read the link.