# file:// HTML link doesn't open

Tags: file, hyperlink, href

I need to link to a file not served by a webserver, so i'm using this HTML sintax

```
<a href="file:///C:/demoAttachments/demo.pdf" target="_blank">demo.pdf</a>
```

Tryed in Chrome, Edge and Firefox: when i click on the link nothing happens. Even right clickeng the link and selecting "Open in a new tab" doesn't work: Firefox and Efge doesn't open the new tab and Chrome opens a new "about:blank" tab.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/upurrvn0/

What's the matter with this?

@DougDawson already found and ridden that question. I've specified that my files are (unluckly) not served by a webserver. Therefore i need to use a "file:///" link, which i read over several websites should be allowed by browsers. If I manually type the address in the URL bar, i get the file (so the URL is ok). If this has became illegal over the years, I haven't found anything. Can you provide any documentation about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The right way of setting <a href=""> when it's a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021781/the-right-way-of-setting-a-href-when-its-a-local-file)

Comment: @DougDawson please read updated question

Comment: The Stack question I referenced does talk about local file links. It also includes a link to a Mozillazine.org page that indicates that Firefox silently blocks file links and offers some possible work arounds. Is that not what you need?

Comment: @DougDawson actually, mine was wider is I tried with Chrome and Edge too. So do I have to assume from this that even Chrome and Edge enforced the same security policies about this as Mozilla did? Also, implementing workarounds through the browser is not a option in my case.

Comment: In the top answer on the linked question, the responder indicated that Mozilla did it first and other browsers followed, but no further documentation was listed. If you are not able to implement a workaround, I'm not sure there is an answer for you then.

Comment: @DougDawson alright, then I ask for a mandatory webserver. Thanks anyway.