# Link to open file - 1) Locally 2) Server

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I need help to open a file from an html page. First, I want to test opening locally and then from a folder on server. Here is the code I have, and none of the three techniques are working. Also, I would like the links to work on any browser.

```
            <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Meeting Minutes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td><a href="file:///C:/website/MeetingMin/Doc1.pdf" target="_blank">Doc1</a></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td><a href="C://website/MeetingMin/" target="Doc2.pdf">Doc2</a></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td colspan="2"><a href="file:///C:\website\MeetingMin\Doc3.pdf">Doc3</a></td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021781/the-right-way-of-setting-a-href-when-its-a-local-file

Answer (score 0):

**None** of your three suggestions will work when your file is uploaded to a server.

- `file:///C:/website/MeetingMin/Doc1.pdf`

  - will open a **local** copy of the file when typed into the browser's
    address bar
  - will not work from `<a href="">`
- `C://website/MeetingMin/` (with `"target="Doc2.pdf`)

  - `C://` isn't valid
  - filenames are not valid for **[`target`](https://html.com/attributes/a-target/)** - it denotes **how** the file should open
  - will not do anything
- `file:///C:\website\MeetingMin\Doc3.pdf`

  - Unix equivalent of `Doc1`
  - will have the same functionality in Windows

---

In order to load files from a server, there are three types of links available to you:

- **relative links**: `<a href="Doc1.pdf">` or `<a href="./Doc1.pdf">`

  - denotes that `Doc1.pdf` is in the **same folder** as the file that it is being linked to from
  - you can prefix `../` to move up directories (`<a href="../../Doc1.pdf">`)
  - will work locally
- **root-relative links**: `<a href="/Doc2.pdf">`

  - denotes that `Doc2.pdf` is in the **root** folder of the website
    (it doesn't matter where the file that links to it resides)
  - will work locally
- **absolute links**: `<a href="https://example.com/Doc3.pdf">`

  - denotes that `Doc3.pdf` is on `example.com` (in this case, it's at the root)
  - won't work locally
  - will work cross-domain

For further reading on pathlinks, I recommend checking out this **[Coffee Cup article](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)**.

Answer (score 0):

you need to prefix it with file://

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Meeting Minutes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td><a href="file://C:/website/MeetingMin/Doc1.pdf" >Doc1</a></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td><a href="file://C:\website\MeetingMin\Doc2.pdf" >Doc2</a></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td colspan="2"><a href="file://C:\website\MeetingMin\Doc3.pdf">Doc3</a></td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: relative link worked locally. Will need to check out once uploaded to server. thnx