# how i create relative path alway begining root

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

I create my web app with php follow mvc model.
When I set path css,img,js,... i use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/style.css">`
in default controller I got css for my page. But when I call action like `http://localhost/assignment/controller/action` i lost my css. relative path become `http://localhost/assignment/controller/action/public/css/style.css` or `http://localhost/assignment/controller/action/param/public/css/style.css`.

Comment: A leading slash (the _"/"_ character) designates the _document root_ location: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css">`. Furthermore, the directory _"public"_ should be assigned as the _document root_ in the configuration file of your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have a configuration or bundler issue.  The quickest - not best fix - for developing would be to move your css file to where the public folder is located.   You need to find the root folder where that link is calling from and link there.

If you are using a bundler or transpiler, you might need to look in the configs for what is being bundled.

Also make sure to follow this format for local files.
[The right way of setting <a href=""> when it's a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021781/the-right-way-of-setting-a-href-when-its-a-local-file)