# what is wrong with my HTML/CSS code for my row of images? They do not seem to be working?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

[this is my code for my portfolio page and the links for my first row of images do not seem to be working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZNp5.png)

[this screenshot shows which images links are not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYaUC.png)

[the CSS for this is here, so not too sure what i have done wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnQca.png)

Comment: Please upload your code as text not ad picture

Comment: Here You have a link with the way to link a local html file [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021781/the-right-way-of-setting-a-href-when-its-a-local-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021781/the-right-way-of-setting-a-href-when-its-a-local-file)

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder structure first. Maybe that is the problem. Also, please write the code in your questions. It's easier for us to see the problem you are facing.

**Added note**

It's better in your case to make the parent element, `div` gallery, a grid.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery {
  margin: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643827982014-87c3f7a14b1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1074&q=80" alt="picture">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643827982014-87c3f7a14b1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1074&q=80" alt="picture">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643827982014-87c3f7a14b1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1074&q=80" alt="picture">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643827982014-87c3f7a14b1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1074&q=80" alt="picture">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643827982014-87c3f7a14b1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1074&q=80" alt="picture">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643827982014-87c3f7a14b1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1074&q=80" alt="picture">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```