# How to add hyperlink functionality with html and css

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML code that includes some css and I want the button to actually have a use like a hyperlink I press it and it takes me to a certain file or web address I have tried using actual hyperlinks inside the field but it looked ugly and I could only press on the hyperlink, I tried adding a HTML default hyperlink button but it cannot be colored.

Here's the code:

```html
<html>
<body style="background-color:rgb(48, 45, 45)">
<font color="white">
<font color="#4CAF50">
<head>
<style>
.button {
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.button1 {background-color: #4CAF50;}
.button2 {background-color: #008CBA;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button class="button button1">Green</button>
<button class="button button2">Blue</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `onclick` element:

```html
    <button onclick="goToStackOverflow()">Click Me</button> 
    <script>
        function goToStackOverflow() {
          document.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com";
        }
    </script>
```

Or you could style an `<a>` element to look like a button

```css
a {
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

a:active {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For linking to a file specifically, you can also use the <a> tag mentioned above but with a relative URL as apposed to an absolute one (AKA, without 'https://www.' included).

For example, if you placed the file in an inner directory off your base directory, you could use the following snippet:

```
<a href="inner/file.html" class="button">File</a>
```

More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021781/the-right-way-of-setting-a-href-when-its-a-local-file).