# HREF File Link Not Opening

Tags: html

This is the code that doesn't allow for a link to open when selected in the browser.  I use the current Firefox browser running under Win10 22H2.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>index.html</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p> </p>
    <p> <a href="file://///Server/web/web_docs_burgess/BurgessPlace_Mitchells.odt">Mitchell's</a> </p>
    <p> <a href="file://///Server/web/web_docs_burgess/BurgessPlace_Mitchells.pdf">Mitchell's PDF</a> </p>
    <p> </p>
  </body>
</html>`
```

Here's what shows in the browser:

[image]

Clicking on either of these links does nothing.  Hovering over a link shows the correct link in the lower left corner of the browser's window.

If I copy the href file link (the text between the " ") and paste it into the browser address bar the file will open as it should.  I haven't a clue what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks so much for any clues offered.

Comment: Use relative links. If the files are in the same folder as the html, then just have `href="BurgessPlace_Mitchells.pdf"`

Comment: Thanks so much for the guidance.  I have done a couple of things based on you all's input: first, I copied the .odt file to the same directory that holds the index.html file.  Then I changed the path within the "" to first show ./BurgessPlace_Mitchells.odt.  This when running index.html this gave me a 404 which is an improvement over no response at all.  Then I removed the ./ from the path and simply entered "BurgessPlace_Mitchells.odt".  This also gave be a 404.

Comment: I should say that these files reside on a NAS box, with the directory structure:                    /web/web_web_docs_burgess.  The index.html file resides in the /web directory.  I'm wondering if this is some kind of permission problem, though the fact that I can open the files from the browser address bar gives me pause about suggesting permissions as the problem.

Comment: Later:  This time I restarted the browser and found that "BurgessPlace_Mitchells.odt", which was placed in the same directory as index.html, did open properly.  It also works with "./BurgessPlace_Mitchells.odt" as long as that file is in that same directory.  If I point to any other directory [/web/web_docs_burgess" it doesn't work, displaying a 404.

Comment: Still Later:  I found this Stack Overflow post ]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021781/the-right-way-of-setting-a-href-when-its-a-local-file] which lead me to use this href construction - /web-docs-burgess/BurgessPlace_Mitchells.pdf - to display a file that was not in the web site's root directory.  Thanks to all for helping me sort this out.  Learned a lot.  Be well

Answer (score 0):

Try this this should lead to the right directory, instead of using a file `href` wich is not proper as a URL in a directory.

```html
<a href="./BurgessPlace_Mitchells.pdf">PDF</a>
<a href="./BurgessPlace_Mitchells.odt">PDF</a>
```