# Issue while opening local folder from ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have built an intranet web-application that is only used inside the company - so security issues do not matter . where we have a link in a web-application that should access a local directory on the local filesystem. When we pass parameter link a windows explorer instance should open with given a directory open.Is there anything i need to do with IIS?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe",@"c:\teste");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do that you'll be trying to spawn an explorer process on the server hosting the web application.

Do you just want to link to a path on the users local machine or at a network location?

[Link to a file share through an anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474702/link-to-a-file-share-through-an-anchor-tag)

Comment: Try as suggested in the answer to the other question then <a href="file://///myserver/myfolder/"> or <a href="file:////c:/myfolder/">