# Can't load text file when debugging locally

Tags: c#, razor

I'm creating a web page which parses a text file and outputs "important" line numbers as hyperlinks that can be clicked by the user and then taken to that line number of the inputted text file. Naturally this means that by clicking the hyperlink the browser must navigate to the text file. The problem lies with that part. When the hyperlinks are clicked, nothing happens. No errors, just nothing.

Here's the relevant cshtml code:

```
<pre>
    @results

    @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.links.Count; i++)
    { 
        if (ViewBag.links[i].isHyperLink == true) 
        {
            {<a href="@ViewBag.links[i].url">@ViewBag.links[i].text</a>} //HYPERLINKS PRINTED TO PAGE HERE
        }  
        if (ViewBag.links[i].isHyperLink == false)
        {
            @ViewBag.links[i].text;
        }
    }
</pre>
```

Here's the relevant C# code:

```
        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(output, @", [0-9]+?\)"); //find matches in txt file
        List<TextandHyperlink> links = new List<TextandHyperlink>(); //create list of hyperlink objects
        TextandHyperlink tempLink = new TextandHyperlink(); //create 

        int length;
        string temp = "";

        // Get line numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < mc.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
                tempLink = new TextandHyperlink();

            length = mc[i].Value.Length;
            temp = mc[i].Value.Substring(2, length - 3);
            tempLink.text = temp;
            tempLink.url = relativePath; //ASSIGN PATH TO TXT FILE HERE
            tempLink.isHyperLink = true;
            links.Add(tempLink);
        }
        ViewBag.links = links;
```

I've verified that relativePath is the correct path to the text file on my pc. Just in case, here's an example of a path I'm using:
relativePath = C:\Users\USER\PROJECT\Website\Website\Home\UploadFiles~/App_Data/Uploads/bloop.txt

Thanks in advance for any help!

edit: Here is the generated html:

```
--------
Summary
--------
Version             23.00.00.00
Error               2   at lines    (09/02/2014-06:13:32.607, <a href="C:\Users\USER\PROJECT\Website\Website\Home\UploadFiles~/App_Data/Uploads/bloop.txt">5662</a>); (09/02/2014-06:15:10.756, <a href="C:\Users\USER\PROJECT\Website\Website\Home\UploadFiles~/App_Data/Uploads/bloop.txt">7397</a>)
Timeouts                0
Inits               1   at lines    (09/02/2014-06:12:59.900, <a href="C:\Users\USER\PROJECT\Website\Website\Home\UploadFiles~/App_Data/Uploads/bloop.txt">2</a>)
```

Comment: Post the HTML that gets generated.  The error is probably there...

Comment: Have you tried Path.Combine? For setting the path.

Comment: I've posted the generated html as an edit. Yes I am using Path.Combine to create relativePath.

Comment: You can't link to filesystem-style path without using the `file://` protocol, i.e. the URL would have to be `file://C/Users...`. However, even then, that will only work running locally because of browser integration with the local file system. Remotely, you'd need to serve the file through your webserver using an actual URL relative to your site's document root.

Comment: You can't link to filesystem-style path without using the `file://` protocol, i.e. the URL would have to be `file://C/Users...`. However, even then, that will only work running locally because of browser integration with the local file system. Remotely, you'd need to serve the file through your webserver using an actual URL relative to your site's document root.

Comment: Grantly also suggested I use the file://// prefix. It works when I paste that path into a browser directly but not when I input it to an href. I also noticed that when I put a garbage path into an href it still doesn't do anything. No error...just nothing.

Comment: @GrantBall I think the trick here is using a different number of slashes in the paste in browser vs in code (in the a href link).  God knows what the right number of slashes is...Take your shoe size, square root, temperature outside plus one... really it makes little sense...

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that your path and filename are correct, then **Permissions** will be another issue.  On a Windows Server machine for example, you will have to ensure that the same 'user' running the exe / **web page** / operation (could be a local account, network service account, etc) has *at least* explicit read rights on that file.  Accessing files from web pages is deliberately difficult as there *has* to be security mechanisms in place, permissions is one of them.

(Mind you - in your error messages - your file path does look dodgey...The floating *tilda* is suspicious)

Comment: After reading your comment, I moved the text file to a folder that certainly has no permission limitations (and updated relativePath, of course) but I still have the same problem. The new file path also had no tilda in it so I'm guessing it's something else. 

I've read that loading files on localhost is "harder" than when the site is actually hosted. I could not find a good answer as to why or how to fix it though.

Comment: Do you want the user to open the file when they click on the link? I don't think href is enough information.  Have you tried file:/// as the prefix?  Try copying your link into a browser and see what happens

Comment: Sorry just an adjunct, file links can be tricky - and sensitive to each application.  Best bet is form the link manually first and verify it in a browser, then simple web page, then in code.

Comment: Okay I've changed the filepath to not include the tilda. When I copy that into a browser directly it works. But when I input that same path to an href it still does nothing. I tried putting file:/// prefix as well to no avail. What do you mean that href is not enough information?

Comment: @GrantBall try this link, they have good examples of how to structure href to include file://// ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474702/link-to-a-file-share-through-an-anchor-tag

Comment: I tried every combination of those examples and none worked. I also noticed that even when I put a garbage filepath the same thing happens. No error or anything. When I put http://www.google.com it works just fine. It's like it doesn't want load files or something.

Comment: @GrantBall I understand fully how frustrating it can be. Persevere! It will work.  The extra slashes are acting as escape characters too, so try with more slashes / less slashes....it could be picky depending on your O/S and your browser and how it treats slashes in file a links.  Perhaps hard code the file name in code, and run your website over and over again until you get the format correct...the Browser can be a pain - when pasting file links into the address bar...(Unsure which one you are using)

Comment: (Possibly one reason any sane developer despises web development....Sends you crazy)

Comment: Thanks :) I think I'll just have to do that. This has been driving me insane.